# Error: Must supply apikey when trying to use react-auto-fill-address

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to make a form that requires your address, and I decided to go with `react-autofill-address` so that it would autofill. I just copied the code from the npm site, and it's giving me the error `Error: Must supply apikey`.

Here's the code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Address from 'react-autofill-address'

class AddressForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  setPlace(place) {
    this.setState({ place })
  }

  render() {
    const { place } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="form-container">
          <div className="header">
            <h1>Creating a Member (cont.)</h1>
          </div>
          <Address
            apikey={process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY}
            onChange={place => this.setPlace(place)}
            timer={300} // Throttle the onChange event
            />
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(place, null, 2)}</pre>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AddressForm;
```

I see the apikey is already set so I'm not sure what's wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console log the process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY you will probably get undefined.  Not sure if you know what an api key is, by your question it's unclear but process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY is not the acutal api key you need to register one with google in your google developers console and set it in you app.

If you do already have an api key then in react you need to usually add REACT_APP_ before all of your environment variables so it would look like process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY or you could just add it manually to your form like `apikey={'your-api-key-here'}`.  Check out how to add custom environment variables here [React Adding Custom Environment Varialbes](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Comment: So I have to go to Google and get an API key for my project? Would I go get the JS one then?

Comment: Yes I'm not sure what API you need to use but i'm assuming it's the places api so you can see here https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key how to obtain an api key.  They are usually free until you hit a certain limit then they charge you but the limit is usually extremely high so you you shouldn't have to worry about it.  All api keys are used for all different types of programing languages you shouldn't have to worry about what language your using it's just a key to verify users so they can have access to the api interface.

Comment: I think I can take it from here then! Thank you :)